# Does Python's ElementTree allow only one namespace mapping?

Tags: python, namespaces, elementtree

I am stumped by ElementTree's namespace handling of namespace mappings. I need to parse various trees having different default namespaces. ElementTree seems to retain the first namespace mapping I specify in find().

In the following code I expect the second pass to barf on finding **D**, because **D** is not in the namespace that gets passed to find(). Instead it *does* find **D** (which has the wrong namespace) but barfs on **B** (which it should find).

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Run code for two namespaces
namespaces = [ "http://www.example.org/X", "http://www.example.org/Y"]
for ns in namespaces:
    try:
        # make an XML document as a string
        xmlString='''
            <A xmlns="{ns}" xmlns:static="http://www.example.org/X">
                <B>
                    <C>sam</C>
                </B>
                <static:D>
                    <C>sam</C>
                </static:D>
            </A>
        '''.format(ns=ns)

        print(xmlString)

        tree = ET.fromstring(xmlString)
        # See what namespace is used for the root element
        print("treetag: {}".format(tree.tag))

        # Find the element with the explicit namespace
        elementD = tree.find("ns0:D", { "ns0":ns})
        assert elementD != None, "elementD not found"
        print("elementD: {}".format(elementD.tag))

        # Find the element with the default namespace
        elementB = tree.find("ns0:B", { "ns0":ns})
        assert elementB != None, "elementB not found"
        print("elementB: {}\n".format(elementB.tag))
    except AssertionError as e:
        print repr(e)
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? If not, how can I force find() to use the proper namespace mapping?

Environment: Mac OS X, Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Comment: Seems like a bug that was not fixed in Python 2.7. With Python 3.7, it does barf on `D` as expected. See https://bugs.python.org/issue17011

Comment: Ah, I hadn't found that in my searches, thanks. I'm surprised that the issue is marked as 'fixed' for Python 2.7 when it clearly isn't.

Comment: Yes, the bug is marked as 'fixed'. But the fix was committed to the 'master' and '3.3' branches only, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been hit by a bug that was fixed in Python 3.3, but not in Python 2.7: https://bugs.python.org/issue17011 ("ElementPath ignores different namespace mappings for the same path expression").

When using Python 3.7, it is indeed the `D` element that causes an AssertionError.